# populate both table rows and its header using the same object with v-for in Vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, loops, html-table, v-for

Is there a way to populate a table headers and rows using a single object?
I wrote the following code but

```
<table v-for="(table, index) in table" :key="index">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        {{ table.header }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{ table.rows }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
-------------
data(){
  return{
      table: {
        headers: ["header 1", "header 2"],
        rows: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3", "row 4"],
      },
  }
}
```

but it doesn't render anything!

I want the two table headers to be:

`header 1` and `header 2`

and the table rows in `header 1` column to be:

`row 1`, `row 2`, `row 3`, `row 4`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could use a [v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for) in your `<td>` element.
It would look something like `<td v-for="(row, index) in table.row" :key="index" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup>
const table = {
  headers: ["header1", "header2"],
  rows: [
    {
      header1: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3", "row 4"],
      header2: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3", "row 4"],
    }
  ]
}
</script>

<template>
  <table v-for="(item, i) in table.headers" :key="i">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          {{ item }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(items, k ) in table.rows" :key="k">
        <td>
          {{ items[item] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

You can try this